# How do I get k where k is from F_k for pdr in muz?

Tags: z3

I'm using the muZ in Z3 and it has this new generalized PDR.  I'm wondering how I can get some data about the PDR algorithm.  The invariants for the PDR algorithm are the following:

```
I => F_0
F_i => F_{i+1} for 0 <= i < k
F_i => P for 0 <= i <= k
F_i /\ T => F'_{i + 1}
```

I'm really interested in the value of k at termination.  Is this statistic available somehow?  I don't see it if I enable :print-statistics true in my query:

```
(query (p x) :print-statistics true)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statistics feature does currently not tell much specific about PDR (it should and thanks for pointing this out). At this point you can get additional information by running it in verbose mode.
It prints the iteration count to the stderr stream.

For example:

```
z3.exe bakery.smt2 /v:1
Entering level 1
Entering level 2
Entering level 3
Entering level 4
Entering level 5
Entering level 6
.... followed by inductive assertions ...
```